# Error: 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: handler'

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, click

I have a user control for a button called ImageButton and in the code behind I have ClickEvent, which looks like this:

```
public RoutedEventHandler ClickEvent
    {
        set { PokeButton.Click += value; }
    }
```

with PokeButton being the name of the button in the user control.

I use the user control in a different window and it looks like this: [image]

```
<b:ImageButton Image="Images/Icons/Pokedex1.png"
                       ImageHeight="30" ImageWidth="35"
                       Text="Search"
                       ClickEvent="BackToSearch_Click"
                       Margin="300,130,0,0"/>
```

The button works as intended; clicking the button calls BackToSearch_Click. However my Visual Studios keeps showing me the blue squigly under ClickEvent="BackToSearch_Click" and keeps giving me the error "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: handler".

I actually haven't encountered this error while working on the project until recently so I wasn't even aware of it (since it worked as intended and the error never popped up before). It's still bugging me because now I'm not sure if I'm handling the button's Click event properly, and I don't understand why it keeps saying the value is null (when it clearly isn't).

Comment: Any particular reason you're not simply using a `Button` ?

Comment: I might be using user controls for the wrong reason, but I thought I was supposed to if I wanted to reuse the button multiple times elsewhere :/

Comment: What it sounds like is its attempting to route BackToSearch_Click back to some type of handler in your code behind and its not finding it.  All you show is public RoutedEventHandler ClickEvent.  Is there really a method in code behind called BackToSearch_Click, if not I would bet that's why you are seeing the blue lines?  Also is there a specific reason the click event wouldn't work in this situation?

Comment: @user3294629 Customizing the `ControlTemplate` of the standard `Button` was a much better solution (you would have been able to use all the `Button`'s properties, events, ..). `UserControl` are typically used for larger, composite UI elements.